# Generate text effects

Tags: scripting

I am trying to find out how to write a script so that whatever text I write a specific text effect is generated. For example, [this website](http://www.flamingtext.com/logo/Design-Fluffy) calls a specific request with some parameters. I want to know what is actually going on here and how can I build something like this?

Comment: Looking in the page source is always a good first step

Comment: In this specific case, it is likely that the text is sent to a server, and a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is invoked there to render the image.

Comment: I checked the network monitor and saw that a request is being sent to their server. Notice that in the web page there it's written script made by "X" using Graphics by Gimp. What does this mean?

Comment: Probably that they’re using Gimp on the server side, possibly through its [command line interface](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). I think Gimp has a powerful scripting language, Script-Fu, and they may be making use of that for their effects. (I know nothing about Script-Fu, though.)